# How can we make the input of a function multiple lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, variable-definitions, input

I want to create a function that takes inputs that are multiple lists of ordered quadruples. For example, when we run the code our input line should read something like inputs[{2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9},...} and return something like {14},{30},... Do I have to use a table for this or is there a way to do this when we define our function? I'm new to this and don't know how I should approach this.

Comment: `f[x___] := Total /@ {x};f[{2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}, {a, b}, {c}]`

Comment: `f[x___] := List /@ Total /@ {x};
f[{2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}, {a, b}, {c}]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want the braces for the output as you say, then you could do something like this with a pure function:

```
someInput = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10, 4}]
{Total[#]} & /@ someInput

(* {{5, 9, 9, 9}, {2, 7, 3, 4}, {8, 4, 4, 8}, {5, 10, 8, 
  5}, {2, 7, 2, 2}, {6, 6, 5, 2}, {3, 8, 9, 6}, {8, 6, 5, 2}, {2, 10, 
  10, 1}, {2, 9, 3, 2}}

 {{32}, {16}, {24}, {28}, {13}, {19}, {26}, {21}, {23}, {16}} *)
```

I will note that Total doesn't care that the input list was ordered as you originally said.  I encourage you to look at pure functions - they are used often and once you get used to them, you'll use them all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Table` or `Map` functions.

```
ClearAll[fun] ;
fun[list_List:{a_,b_,c_,d_}] := Total[list]  ;
args = {{a1,b1,c1,d1},{a2,b2,c2,d2}} ;
Map[fun,args]
Table[fun[arg],{arg,args}]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's best not to rely on input having a particular form, so ideally we would solve this in a way that added the elements of a list of lists regardless of whether they were of the same length as in the OP.

A way to do this looks at the `//FullForm` of the list of lists, which is something like `List[List[1,2,3],List[2,3,4,5],...]` and replaces the internal `List` heads with `Plus`. This will work regardless of how long each sublist is.

```
Plus @@ myList[[#]] & /@ Range[Length[myList]]
```

We need the `[[#]]&` Pure Function because otherwise `Plus` will add the first element of each list, then the second, etc. `Plus@@myList` therefore fails with an error if the sublists are of equal length, or gives the wrong answer if they are of equal length.

**Alternatively**

*Provided* your numeric input lists are all of equal length (not necessarily quads), this will work:

```
quadList = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {8, 4}]
Total[Transpose[quadList]]

(* {{5, 3, 2, 2}, {5, 3, 4, 4}, {4, 2, 3, 2}, 
{1, 4, 5, 3}, {1, 5, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 2, 3}, {5, 2, 2, 5}}

{12, 16, 11, 13, 12, 5, 11, 14} *)
```

This will also work, where we use the `Blank[]` to tell the ReplaceAll what it is replacing, but it depends on the lists being of equal length and will crash otherwise.

```
{{5,3,2,2},{5,3,4,4}}/.x_->Total[Transpose[x]]
```

To define a function that tests whether the input lists are of equal length we could use this, but the approach is clumsy compared with the `Plus@@` solution that doesn't require equal-length lists, and answers already given by others also represent good alternatives:

```
sumList1[x_] := If[SameQ[Sequence @@ (Length[#] & /@ x)], Total[Transpose[x]], Print["Lists must be of equal length"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is a *list* of lists, you can use the two-argument form of `Total` (i.e.`Total[input, {2}]`) to get the row sums, and `Map (/@)` `List` on the output:

```
ClearAll[f1a]
f1a[x : {{__} ..}] := List /@ Total[x, {2}]

f1a[{{2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}, {a, b}, {c}}]
```

> ```
> {{14}, {30}, {a + b}, {c}}
> ```

Alternatively, you can `Apply (@@@)` `Plus` at level `1` and map `List` on the output:

```
ClearAll[f2a]
f2a[x : {{__} ..}] := List /@ (Plus @@@ x)

f2a[{{2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}, {a, b}, {c}}]
```

> ```
> {{14}, {30}, {a + b}, {c}}
> ```

If the input is a *sequence* of lists, we need wrap the input sequence with `List`:

```
ClearAll[f1b]
f1b[x : {__} ..] := List /@ Total[{x}, {2}]
f1b[{2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}, {a, b}, {c}]
```

> ```
> {{14}, {30}, {a + b}, {c}}
> ```

```
ClearAll[f2b]
f2b[x : {__} ..] := List /@ (Plus @@@ {x})

f2b[{2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}, {a, b}, {c}]
```

> ```
> {{14}, {30}, {a + b}, {c}}
> ```

And for fun, Halloween-special versions of the above:

```
ClearAll[☺]
☺ = +## & @@@ {#} & /@ # &;

☺[{{2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}, {a, b}, {c}}]
```

> ```
> {{14}, {30}, {a + b}, {c}}
> ```

```
ClearAll[☺☺]
☺☺ = +## & @@@ {#} & /@ {##} &;

☺☺[{2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}, {a, b}, {c}]
```

> ```
> {{14}, {30}, {a + b}, {c}}
> ```